# How to format turnstile to expand over several lines?

Tags: turnstile

I saw an example in the book *forallx-formal-logic*, where it formats the deduction proof by expanding the turnstile over several lines while having equations above and below its 'arm'. I wonder how it is possible in latex.

[image: An example of expanded turnstile]

Answer (score 1):

This can be simulated simply with nested tabulars:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|l}
    1 & $\exists x.x \ni A $ \\\cline{2-2}\\[-10pt]
    2 & \multirow{3}{*}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l}
    $A=\varnothing $ \\\cline{1-1}
    ... \\
    ... \\
\end{tabular}}
 \\
    3 &  \\
    4 &  \\
    5 & $A\neq\varnothing $   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```